# SharePoint list view web part wildcard search

Tags: sharepoint-online, wildcard-search

I am trying to use the following code to filter List View Web Parts in SharePoint Online.

It works well when the 2 text boxes are filled in but not when one of them remains empty.

Does anyone have an idea why the Else condition doesn't work? Thanks for your support.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The values are not `== null` when empty, they are `== ""`.

Try updating your tests to:

```
if (cust != "") 
{
  if(adr != "")
  {
....
```

and it should work. As the inputs exists the values will be blank, not `null`or `undefined`.

The reason it currently works when both are filled out is because the two first tests will always be == true.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've changed != null to != "" but the redirected url is still ?FilterField1=Title&FilterValue1=VALUEOFTEXTBOX&FilterOp1=Contains&FilterField2=WFFullProjectID&FilterValue2=&FilterOp2=Contains
It doesn't move to the else conditions

Comment: You updated all of the tests?

Comment: Yes I did (the 3 conditions)

Comment: Try adding some logging and check what the values actually are, then you can debug as well... Could be something else on the page that is interfering